# Blazor Server-Side JS Invoking

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

Hi I'm trying to move the bytes of my video which is in c# to javascript to make the bytes into URL.createObjectURL on Blazor server-side

I moved the bytes using Js Invoke

.cs

```
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.PathFile))
         {

           //Byte Video
            byte[] result = GetFile(item.PathFile);

            if (result != null)
               {                            
               
                  var url = await Js.InvokeAsync<string>("videoUrl", result);
                  data.ImageString = url;

                }
          }
```

.js

```
function videoUrl(value) {

            var byteCharacters = atob(value);
            var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            //Byte Array -> Blob
            var file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'data:video/mp4;base64' });
            //Blob -> Object URL
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
           
            return fileURL;

        }
```

My problem is, I tried this script for a video with a size of 3 Mb it runs fine, but when I try for a 133Mb video I get an error:

> Error: System.ArgumentException: The JSON value of length 139569235 is too large and not supported.

I've tried to fix it, but it still fails, it makes me a little frustrated

So is there a solution for my error ? or what should I do?

**I thank you for any suggestions or feedback**

Comment: I would personally generate a one-time token, send that to the JS function, and use fetch in JS to request the file from a server api - rather than doing it all over the Blazor SignalR connection. If you must do it your way, send it in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

So, reading on the AspNetDocs github, there is a startup option that can change the max message size, but I think it only applies to calls from JS to .Net (https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/21208). Worth a check though.

```
services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddHubOptions(options => options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 32000);
```

Personally though, I would do as Mister Magoo said in the comment and either use an API or chunk the data and reassemble at the other end.